# Extracting a convergent sequence out of a double sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a compact Hausdroff space. Suppose that there exists a double sequence $\{y_n^k\}_{n.k} \subset X$ such that for each fixed $n$, the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty}y_n^k=x_n$. Also $\lim_nx_n=x_0$. I want to conclude that there exists a subsequence, say $\{z_n\}_n$ such that $z_n \to x_0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x_0$. Then there exists $n_U \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \ge n_U$ we have $x_n \in U$. Since $x_{n_U} \in U$, there exists $k(n_U) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y_{n_u}^{k(n_U)} \in U$. So I thought of $\{y_{n_U}^{k(n_U)}\}_U$, where the open sets are arranged by reverse inclusion, i.e $U\le V \iff V \subset U$. This gives me a net. I don't know how to extract a sequence.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What makes you think this is true ? I think I see a counterexample.

Comment: I thought that the compactness would help in someway.

Comment: No, I dont see that. The place to look for counterexamples for this sort of thing is $2^{[0,1]}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compactness of $X$ doesn’t help to extract a convergent sequence out of a double sequence, because if we take a completely regular space $X$ with a double sequence $Y$ not allowing such an extraction and embed $X$ in its compactification $X^*$ then $Y$ in $X^*$ still not allows the extraction. So it suffices to present a counterexample for a Tychonoff space $X$, which is well-known, see Example 1.6.9 of Engelking’s “General topology”.

[image]